# Is there a way to have sonarqube ignore an entire file from inside the (C#) code file

Tags: sonarqube

I'm wresting with SonarQube reporting errors on C# files which I didn't write. For example, I might import a particular piece of code from an open source library where I didn't want to take the entire library as a dependency.

This usually raises a lot of SQ warnings.

Instead of dealing with these one by one, is there a way to just mark the entire file to be ignored? I'n thinking something similar to the new `#nullable disable` directive.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is way to remove or better to say exclude the particular files from being analysed by sonarqube.
You can use the `sonar.exclusions`which is a sonar analysis parameter, using this parameter you can exclude files or folders.

Here is the article from sonarqube on this https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/